# Error OCI_INVALID_HANDLE in Oracle OCI C Code

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I get an error of invalid Handle when `OCIStmtFetch2` function executes in my code.

```
char *query = "SELECT id FROM id_table WHERE ROWNUM <= :1";
rc = OCIStmtPrepare(stmt, errhp, (OraText*)query, strlen(query), OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT);

OCIBind *bindp = NULL;
sb2 pos = 1;
int key=13;
rc = OCIBindByPos(stmt, &bindp, errhp, 1, &key, sizeof(int), SQLT_INT, (dvoid*)&pos, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);

char output[key][120];
sb2 output_ind[1];
ub2 output_len[1];
ub2 output_code[1];
OCIDefine *defnpp;
rc = OCIDefineByPos(stmt, &defnpp, errhp, 1, (dvoid*)output, 120, SQLT_STR, (dvoid*)output_ind, output_len, output_code, OCI_DEFAULT);

int rows = key;
/* execute */
rc = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmt, errhp, key, 0, NULL, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);


rc = OCIStmtFetch2(stmt, errhp, 0, OCI_DEFAULT, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

If I bind the placehoder :1 with integer value 12 then the code works, any value greater than 12 gives me `Error OCI_INVALID_HANDLE` error after running `OCIStmtFetch2`. I have the following code to catch error, which I run after each OCI functions mentioned in the code above

```
if (rc != OCI_SUCCESS && rc != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
  report_error(checkerr("Function Name()", errhp, rc));
  return 1;
}
```

Can anyone please help me what is incorrect in my code? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the `output_ind`, `output_len` and `output_code` arrays be big enough to fit all selected rows? And for the `output` array, what if there are more than 13 rows?

Comment: I have increased the size of all those variables and it worked. Can you please tell me that what each of them do? I got this template so doesnt know every bit of it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working for any value greater than 12 because you are defining your output array to be `char output[13][120]`. I think you already got the idea from Joachim's comment that your output buffer is insufficient for more rows. 
I'll try to answer your follow-up question about ind, rlen and rcode variables in the function call -

```
rc = OCIDefineByPos(stmt, &defnpp, errhp, 1, (dvoid*)output, 120, SQLT_STR, (dvoid*)output_ind, output_len, output_code, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

`OCIDefineByPos` associates an item in a select list with the type and output data buffer.

`output_ind` here is a pointer to an indicator array. Each bind and define OCI call has a parameter that associates an indicator variable, or an array of indicator variables, with a DML statement, a PL/SQL statement, or a query. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci02bas.htm#LNOCI16231) you can know more about indicator variables and their usage.

`output_len` here is a pointer to array of length of data fetched.

`output_code` here is pointer to array of column-level return codes.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question. If i try to fetch 100000 rows and set the size of output* arrays to 100000, I get error: Segmentation fault (core dumped). How to overcome that? thank you

Comment: @Imran, A  segfault is usually an indicator of an invalid memory access - array overwrite, null pointer, bad pointer, stuff like that. Without the actual code it's a pretty vague error message. http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html might help.